# Cannot resolve symbol "FirebaseInstanceId"

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use FirebaseInstanceId but keep getting the error

> "Cannot resolve symbol FirebaseInstanceId".

The modules gradle includes

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:+'
}
```

The only thing which exists on com.google.firebase.iid seems to be .zzb. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you have all of these

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1'

 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0' // not necessary(required for signout and sign in)
```

**Just this much is required.**

Answer (score 3):

Old questions but still relevant so here's an updated answer:
As of now (sept 2020) only `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'`
is required in your app/build.gradle file (see referenced official doc).

*To further add information that I've struggled to find elsewhere when I've researched how to implement push notifications for Android:*
I'm assuming you're using FirebaseInstanceId to retrieve the Instance ID token created by Firebase and are following the guide (see linked documentation). If your main goal is to implement push notifications and you're using React Native I've found you don't need to create the MyFirebaseMessagingService that extends FirebaseMessagingService - you can implement the library react-native-firebase/app and react-native-firebase/messaging to access the token in clients App.

Install both `@react-native-firebase/app` and `@react-native-firebase/messaging`
Then in your frontend App.js:
`import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';`

```
async function requestUserPermission() {  
  const getFcmToken = async () => {
    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
      console.log(fcmToken);
      console.log('Your Firebase Token is:', fcmToken);
    } else {
      console.log('Failed', 'No token received');
    }
  };
  const authStatus = await messaging().requestPermission();
  const enabled =
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.AUTHORIZED ||
    authStatus === messaging.AuthorizationStatus.PROVISIONAL;

  if (enabled) {
    getFcmToken();
    console.log('Authorization status:', authStatus);
  }
}
requestUserPermission();
```

*I'm sure this can be refactored, please suggest edits :)*
[Official documentation Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#add_firebase_sdks_to_your_app)
[React Native Firebase library](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)

Comment: This is JavaScript solution (ReactNative). Thanks for the link to docs.

Answer (score 2):

This is the old version. `FirebaseInstanceIdService` is deprecated

```
package com.example.xxxxxxx.fcm;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService{

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshToken) {
    }
}
```

The new version is

```
package com.example.xxxxxxx.fcm;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class MyFirebaseInstanceIdService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        String refreshToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshToken) {
    }
}
```

Here is the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#set-up-firebase-and-the-fcm-sdk

Comment: In new version we cannot access refreshToken using FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken() right?

Answer (score 1):

Only use the dependency `firebase-messaging` with `firebase-core`

firebase-iid is not required to be declared as dependency.

Here is the documentation : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#set-up-firebase-and-the-fcm-sdk

Answer (score 0):

```
fun setNewFcm() {
    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (!task.isSuccessful) {
            return@addOnCompleteListener
        }
        if (task.result != null) {
            val token: String = task.result
            AppSharedData.setFcmToken(token)
        }
    }
}
```

Or by using this

```
fun setNewFcm() {
    FirebaseInstallations.getInstance().getToken(true)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                return@addOnCompleteListener
            }
            if (task.result != null) {
                val token: String = task.result.token
                AppSharedData.setFcmToken(token)
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).