# cannot find symbol class FirebaseInstanceId in my android studio project

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
^
symbol:   class FirebaseInstanceId
location: package com.google.firebase.iid

The code is in my RNPushNotifications.java file and I have tried changing multiple versions of firebase core and messaging, but nothing seems to help.

PS: also tried solutions given in [Cannot resolve symbol "FirebaseInstanceId"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49129901/cannot-resolve-symbol-firebaseinstanceid)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method and class is deprecated in the latest versions,now you can use `FirebaseMessaging` class to get the Device token, like this

```
      FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
            .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                    sendFCMTokenToDatabase(task.getResult());
                }
            });
```

Here `task.getResult()` method will provide you with FCM token.

Comment: Can you please tell me from where to import sendFCMTokenToDatabase.

Comment: That was my method, you can ignore it.